# How cakePHP build form data

Tags: arrays, forms, cakephp, input

i've created a form that loop in my table and give me some images:

id1: ->Image path, title etc
id2: -> Image path title etc

i've created my view in this way:

```
<div>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Gallery', 
                array( 'action' => 'save')); ?>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->PhpThumb->thumbnail($image['medias']['file'], array('w' => 75, 'h' => 75)); ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('title'.$image['medias']['id'], array('value' => $image['medias']['title']));?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('description'.$image['medias']['id'], array('value' => $image['medias']['description']));?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

After submit, i have an array like this:

```
array(
'Gallery' => array(
    'title19' => 'test',
    'description19' => '',
    'title20' => '',
    'description20' => '',
    'title21' => '',
    'description21' => '',
    'title22' => '',
    'description22' => ''
)
```

)

For sure, i cant use the save() method because the array isnt well formatted. I think the right format should be:

```
array(
'Gallery' => array(
    array('id' => 19,
          'title => 'test',
          'description => ''),
    array( 'id' =>20,
            title => '',
            description => '') 
)
```

)

but, how can i get this ? Or some array that is right formatted?

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over them put the iterator or id in the right place:

```
$this->Form->input('Model.' . $i . 'field');
$this->Form->input('Model.' . $i . 'other_field');
```

References:

- [Saving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)
- [Form Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

Comment: I've modified in this way:

    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('Gallery.'.$image['medias']['id'].'title', array('value' => $image['medias']['title']));?></td>

but it produces:

    array(
 'Gallery' => array(
  '19title' => 'test',
  '19description' => '',
  '20title' => '',
  '20description' => '',
  '21title' => '',
  '21description' => '',
  '22title' => '',
  '22description' => ''
 )
)

Comment: Watch the syntax... missing dot.